# Why is this posting the ID when it is meant to be posting the company name?

Tags: php, mysql, post, mysqli

I got this code to work, mostly.  I have an issue in where it is posting the comp_id instead of the name, which is the company.

I can't figure out why. Can someone here look at this code and tell me where the error is?

The table is comp, the fields are comp_id and name.

The test page is: http://kaboomlabs.com/PDI/test4.php

I know I'm missing something but I've been staring at this code for too long and I don't see the obvious mistakes any more. Thanks.

```
<?php
 require_once('connectvars.php');
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL .');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $comp = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['comp']);
}


//Access the Database
    if (!empty($comp)) {
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

    $query = "INSERT INTO ncmr (comp) VALUES ('$comp')";

    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($dbc) . "<hr>\nQuery: $query");
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }


echo "<form method='post'>";
        echo '<fieldset>';
            echo'<div id="comp">';
             $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
        $mysqli->select_db('comp');
            echo '<span class="b">Company:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';
            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM comp"); 
            $i = 0;
            echo "<SELECT name='comp'>\n";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($i == 4) echo '<option value="lines">-----</option>';
            echo "<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}                                 </option>\n";
            $i++;}
        echo "</select>\n";
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Submit NCMR" name="submit" /></div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: Well... Don't just stare at the code. Do some active debugging such as inspecting the generated HTML in your browser, displaying the received post values with `var_dump()`, inspecting the generated SQL code...

Comment: you're getting a `mysqli_real_escape_string()` warning on your page. Is the first parameter in your `mysqli_connect();` function a link identifier?

Comment: @Sooper, I don't know.  I'm noticing that too.  @ Alvaro, How?

Comment: More than anything else: Please stop intermixing database queries with the HTML. Break all the queries into a library of functions that return arrays of the data you need, then foreach() over them to build your form, It'll be much clearer and easier to debug and upgrade.

Comment: @DampeS8N  How do you do that?

Comment: Start by looking into [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) and [includes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) in PHP.

Comment: @DampeS8N, will this allow me to post, or is this just something to coax your ego in showing that you know more than me, because I am looking at what you told me to do, and it doesn't show why I get an error though. Sorry if I sound snippy, but I don't need to change the code again to make it easier to read.  What I need to do is to get it working the way it needs to.  Right now it's not, and I'd like to know why. I'll go back and streamline it once I know it works correctly.

Comment: Matt, this is a better way of structuring your code which will make it both easier to debug, because you can easily isolate data gathering from data display and also because there is less to think about all at once. But additionally it will allow you to reuse those functions on other pages, letting you reuse code and more importantly be able to update the reused code in a single location. I'm not trying to look better than you, I'm trying to make your life easier and save you time.

Comment: @DampeS8N I'll look into it, I got it to post, but at this time it is still showing no errors but the data it is culling is not pulling correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue, the people here helped, and pointed me in the right direction. The problem was that not one person gave the correct answer, but multiple people gave part of the complete answer.

Here is the script in it's entirety.

```
<?php
 require_once('connectvars.php');
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL .');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $comp = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['comp']);
}


//Access the Database
    if (!empty($comp)) {
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
    $query = "INSERT INTO ncmr (comp) VALUES ('$comp')";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($dbc) . "<hr>\nQuery: $query");
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }
echo "<form method='post'>";
    echo '<fieldset>';
        echo'<div id="comp">';
            $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
                $mysqli->select_db('comp');
            echo '<span class="b">Company:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';
                $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM comp"); 
                $i = 0;
            echo "<SELECT name='comp'>\n";
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if ($i == 4) echo '<option value="lines">-----</option>';
            echo "<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>\n";
                $i++;
            }
        echo "</select>\n";
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Submit NCMR" name="submit" /></div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your options values are the IDs of the comps, and when you submit a form with dropdowns, what gets sent is the value of the selected option for every dropdown, not the text displayed.

You should change this line:

```
       echo "<option value='{$row['comp_id']}'>{$row['name']}</option>\n";
```

For this:

```
    echo "<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>\n";
```

Let me know if that helps you!

**Edit**
There were actually 2 errors on your code, the first one was the change above, and the second one is the fact that your `form` tag has no `action` attribute.
You need to specify that for the form to post something somewhere.

It should be like this:

`<form method="post" action="your_script.php">`

And on your_script.php you need to catch the parameters with `$_POST['comp']`

Let me know if that solves the problem!

Comment: I am getting an error now: 


Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in \kaboomlabs.com/PDI/test4.php on line 5

Comment: This is because you defined `$dbc` after you tried to use it as an argument to `mysqli_real_escape_string`. See the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Sorry not switching it to a mix of php and html.  I've spent too long attempting to get this work using php. I'd like an answer in php usage only please.

Comment: @Deleteman I've done what you said, now it's not posting at all.

Comment: @MattRidge You probably have another error there, because the change I propposed can't affect the form in that way. Do you have some other error message?

Comment: @Deleteman Nope.  I'm reposting the code above with your adjustments.It still posts the number, not the name, even though it is there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you really shouldn't be using `echo` to output all of your HTML like that. It is better to do something like this:

```
<?php
    // Connect to database, etc...
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `comp`);
?>
<!-- Output your HTML here, outside of PHP tags -->
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div id="comp">
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="lines">-----</option>
            <option value='<?php echo $row['name']; ?>'><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

I omitted a lot of the code, but I hope you get the idea.

The reason you are POSTing the `comp_id` field is because that is the value of your `<option>` elements. The browser does not POST what is between the tags (the "inner HTML"), it posts the `value` attribute. I showed this change above:

```
<option value='{$row['comp_id']}'>{$row['name']}</option>
```

should be:

```
<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>
```

Lastly, the reason you are getting a `mysqli_real_escape_string` error is because this line:

```
$comp = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comp']));
```

Comes BEFORE:

```
 $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($dbc) . "<hr>\nQuery: $query");
```

So when you are giving `mysqli_real_escape_string` the `$dbc` parameter, it has no idea what that is, because you are defining `$dbc` after you try to provide it as a parameter.